# How to detect if an object is moved to another division<div>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So basically I am making a todo list web app with RPG level up features.

For the todo tasks you created, I use jQuery to allow you to drag the task across three divisions, essentially the idea is to allow you categorize those tasks, i.e. "Pending", "in Progress", "Completed".

So for the RPG part, I want to let the user gain experience if, say, they move a task to the "completed" category.

So the question is, how do I detect such a behavior in Javascript or in jQuery? (Moving an task object to a specific devision)

Comment: Please provide somo more description, like part of html, css and javascript you have used so someone can help you

Comment: Don't expect everyone to understand abbreviations. Please define "RPG". To me it means "Rocket Propelled Grenade"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're dropping your tasks into each category. Ideally, you'd want an onComplete/ onAfter event handler. If you're using a plugin to handle the drag and drop, look at the documentation to see if it supports an onComplete/onAfter.

So, a simple way of doing it could be:

When the onComplete/onAfter event handler triggers, check to see if the length of your "Completed" list has increased by one. If so, award experience.

There are other ways to do it, but generally you want to listen for some kind of event that happens when you move tasks around.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `.parent()` function to get the `<div>` that contains the task object.